# Searchable Custom Field doesn't appear in Quicksearch options list and is not a sort option in reports

Tags: custom-fields, civireport

I have 2 membership custom fields that are set as searchable. One field is integer the other is alphanumeric. Neither field appears in the Quicksearch options in Search Preferences. The custom fields appear as column options in the membership reports but they are not available as sort options.
Is there anything else I need to configure to make them available for search or sortable in reports?

I have tested with a Contact custom field and this works as expected.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What type of data is in these fields? Is it plain text, a boolean value, a date etc.?

Comment: I have updated the question .. one field is integer and the other is alphanumeric.

Comment: What version of civicrm are your using? Are you able to duplicate this behaviour on dmaster? https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ (If not then it's either a bug that's been fixed in a more recent version of civicrm, or a problem specific to your install)

Comment: I am using 5.21.0. I have tried on the dmaster demo server and get the same results. It seems that a membership custom field does not work the same way as a contact custom field as a contact custom field will appear in the Quicksearch list and is sortable. Is this by design or because of the way the data is stored in the tables?

Answer (score 1):

The quicksearch function is for searching contacts, and therefore doesn't call to any of the other components of Civi for data fields.

[As per Civi's Docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/), if you're looking for data regarding a specific component (i.e Memberships), each component has it's own search function. In Find Memberships, this should also show your custom fields to allow you to search from.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The membership number in the custom field is our primary key to our members so not being able to use it in the Quicksearch is a pain. My other requirement was to use it as a sortable field in reports but that doesn't seem possible either. What I have decided to do is add a contact custom field and write a civirules action which will keep this custom field in step with the membership custom field.

Comment: dear @Crofter how did you get CiviRules to write a field from membership entity to contact entity? What action is used to solve this problem?